# using the ave function in R - count number of unique months per person

Tags: r

I want to count the number of rows per person (hai_dispense_number) per month (month) in the following dataframe. My overall aim is to see if the mean count of rows increases from April to September. I'm pretty sure I should use the ave function to make a count variable. But all my attempts aren't working for me. See attempts below. Once I have the counts made, I think I'll be able to use ddply to do a mean summary per month. below is a toy df with the column 'obs' my desired output.

```
df
         hai_dispense_number date_of_claim hai_atc     month obs
9972511   Patient HAI0002664    2010-04-07 A10BA02     april   1
11376245  Patient HAI0002664    2010-05-04 A10BA02       may   1
12508505  Patient HAI0002664    2010-05-31 A10BA02       may   2
13480611  Patient HAI0002664    2010-06-30 A10BA02      june   1
13486327  Patient HAI0002664    2010-06-30 A10BH03      june   2
13567944  Patient HAI0002664    2010-06-08 A10BA02      june   3
15003657  Patient HAI0002664    2010-07-27 A10BA02      july   1
15003658  Patient HAI0002664    2010-07-27 A10BH03      july   2
16600413  Patient HAI0002664    2010-08-31 A10BB09    august   1
16600866  Patient HAI0002664    2010-08-23 A10BA02    august   2
16600867  Patient HAI0002664    2010-08-23 A10BH03    august   3
17537505  Patient HAI0002664    2010-08-27 A10BB09    august   4
19176349  Patient HAI0002664    2010-09-17 A10BB09 september   1
19176350  Patient HAI0002664    2010-09-17 A10BH03 september   2
19176358  Patient HAI0002664    2010-09-17 A10BA02 september   3
17765433  Patient HAI0006637    2010-09-17 A10BA02 september   4
12953451  Patient HAI0007418    2010-06-04 A10BA02      june   1
15786889  Patient HAI0007418    2010-07-28 A10BB09      july   1
15787103  Patient HAI0007418    2010-07-12 A10BB09      july   2
15787233  Patient HAI0007418    2010-07-05 A10BA02      july   3
15878776  Patient HAI0007418    2010-07-08 A10BB09      july   4
15908690  Patient HAI0007418    2010-07-23 A10BB09      july   5
17363576  Patient HAI0007418    2010-08-20 A10BB09    august   1
17554737  Patient HAI0007418    2010-08-13 A10BB09    august   2
```

Prior attempts

```
df$obs<-with(df, ave(month, hai_dispense_number, FUN=seq_along))  ##doesn't split by month

df$obs<-with(df, ave(month, hai_dispense_number, FUN=cumsum))  ##gives all NA values, think seq_along is actually what I want

df$obs <- ave(df$month, df$month, FUN=seq_along)  ##this is better than the previous two, but doesn't seem to split by person

ddply(df,~month,summarise,mean=mean(obs)) ##this works absolutely fine, just need to counts right first!
```

Would value any input anyone could offer me. Seems like I'm getting something fundamental wrong here.

Comment: If you 'only' need to count each combination of factor levels you may try `table`. Could this be something: `with(df, data.frame(table(hai_dispense_number, month)))`?

Comment: @Henrik nice and simple solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I have trimmed down your data to this:

```
> head(df)
            patient month
9972511  HAI0002664 april
11376245 HAI0002664   may
12508505 HAI0002664   may
13480611 HAI0002664  june
13486327 HAI0002664  june
13567944 HAI0002664  june
```

That's all we need since we are working with patient identifiers and months only. To get the required new column, try this:

```
library(plyr)

> ddply(df, .(patient, month), mutate, obs = 1:length(month))
      patient     month obs
1  HAI0002664     april   1
2  HAI0002664    august   1
3  HAI0002664    august   2
4  HAI0002664    august   3
5  HAI0002664    august   4
6  HAI0002664      july   1
7  HAI0002664      july   2
8  HAI0002664      june   1
9  HAI0002664      june   2
10 HAI0002664      june   3
11 HAI0002664       may   1
12 HAI0002664       may   2
13 HAI0002664 september   1
14 HAI0002664 september   2
15 HAI0002664 september   3
16 HAI0006637 september   1
17 HAI0007418    august   1
18 HAI0007418    august   2
19 HAI0007418      july   1
20 HAI0007418      july   2
21 HAI0007418      july   3
22 HAI0007418      july   4
23 HAI0007418      july   5
24 HAI0007418      june   1
```

Incidentally, I assume that in your sample output the obs = 4 for September is a type since the patient identifier has changed from the previous three (2664 to 6637).

Comment: thank you for this. works really well. and yes, you picked up my mistake on the sample output - thanks!